# How to access or create reference to widgets in a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have created a class taht extends from `DialogFragment`. I went with the custom layout and I added some buttons to this dialog.

I defined fields to the buttons but when I launch the dialog from the main activity I get nullreferenceexception.

Here is the dialog class:

public class PickRewardDialog extends DialogFragment{

```
private Button mButtonAddCoin;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mButtonAddCoin = (Button) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.button_dialog_reward_get_coin);
    mButtonAddCoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getDialog().getContext().getApplicationContext(), "You will" +
                    " receive 5 coins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(getDialog() != null){
        getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Resources res = getActivity().getResources();
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_pick_reward, null))
    //Positive button
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_choose_reward_positive_button,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //do nothing or Dismiss()
                }
            }
    );

    return builder.create();
}
```

}

and the layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFBB33"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/dialog_title_pick_your_reward"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add 5 coins to your account!"
    android:id="@+id/button_dialog_reward_get_coin"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get a temorary boost on leaderboard!"
    android:id="@+id/button_doalog_reward_boost"/>
```

So the question is how can I set the clicklistener and do stuff with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dialog is not available in the `onCreate()` callback of the `Fragment` so the `mButtonAddCoin` reference will be null. Instead, setup the `Button` in the `onCreateDialog()` callback where you actually inflate the dialog's view:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Resources res = getActivity().getResources();
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_pick_reward, null);
    mButtonAddCoin = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button_dialog_reward_get_coin);
    mButtonAddCoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getDialog().getContext().getApplicationContext(), "You will" +
                    " receive 5 coins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    builder.setView(dialogView);
    //Positive button
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_choose_reward_positive_button,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //do nothing or Dismiss()
                }
            }
    );

    return builder.create();
}
```